# Token "(" is invalid error calling a function that assigns into a custom type containing a json type

Tags: json, postgresql, runtime-error, composite

I'm decoding a JWT with Postgresql. The function `test` is a simplified version of what it actually does. Here it serves to show an error message that I'm getting too.

```
CREATE TYPE parts AS (header json, payload json, valid boolean);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verify(token text, secret text, algorithm text DEFAULT 'HS256')
RETURNS parts AS $$
  SELECT
    '{"alg": "HS256","typ": "JWT"}'::json AS header,
    '{"id": 1, "exp": 1524683318}'::json AS payload,
    TRUE AS valid;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(token text)
RETURNS parts AS $$
  DECLARE
    jwt_parts parts;
  BEGIN
    SELECT verify(test.token, 'secret')
    INTO jwt_parts;

    RETURN jwt_parts;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

After running `SELECT test('xx')` this is the error I'm getting (on Postgres v10.1):

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
>   DETAIL:  Token "(" is invalid.
>   CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: (...
>   PL/pgSQL function test(text) line 5 at SQL statement

I would like to `SELECT ... INTO` my custom `parts` type. I have tried many ways to rephrase, but I suspect this can be done much simpler than what I've tried so far.

*PS: The real function `test(token text)` I'm using is larger and needs the `plpgsql` language.
PS2: Just to make sure that the currently given answers make sense to people visiting this question. The original version of my question had a test function like this:*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(token text)
RETURNS parts AS $$
  DECLARE
    jwt_parts parts;
  BEGIN
    SELECT ('{"alg": "HS256","typ": "JWT"}', '{"id": 1, "exp": 1524683318}', TRUE)
    INTO jwt_parts;

    RETURN jwt_parts;
  END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: `jwt_parts := verify('xxx', 'yyy');` instead of `select .. into ..` works - but I am not sure why (but it's better anyway to use an assignment rather than a select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses cause you to select a single column (of type row), where you actually need three columns.  For example:

```
select (1,2,3)
>>
   row
--------
 (1,2,3)
(1 row)
```

So omit the parentheses after `select`:

```
SELECT ('{"alg": "HS256","typ": "JWT"}', '{"id": 1, "exp": 1524683318}', TRUE)
      ^^^                                                                   ^^^
```

In reply to your comment, the error in your new query comes from:

```
SELECT verify('xxx', 'yyy')
INTO jwt_parts;
```

This again tries to assign a single column to a three-column type.  Instead, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM verify('xxx', 'yyy')
INTO jwt_parts;
```

Comment: Your new function has `LANGUAGE sql;`, should be `plpgsql`.  I've updated the answer, although it's better to ask new questions in new question.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't select a tuple but a regular row (remove parenthesis):

```
SELECT '{"alg": "HS256","typ": "JWT"}', '{"id": 1, "exp": 1524683318}', TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you! But I realize now that I oversimplified my question. I've changed it. There's one extra function that actually returns the type.